# AngularJS assigning scope variable from scope

Tags: angularjs

In angularJS, when trying to assign a scope variable from the value of another scope variable, the value of the derived variable is empty. In the example, I'd like to have a scope reference for the car, and also for a specific car part (which may change later in the application).

Example:

```
$scope.car = Car.get(); //async http service that returns a JSON car object
$scope.selectedCarPart =  $scope.car.brakes;
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{car.engine}} - {{selectedCarPart}}</div>
```

Output:

```
v8 -
```

Why is *selectedCarPart* empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you `get` call is async, so when you assign the `selectedCarPart`, your `$scope.car` is currently null and doesn't have yet some `brakes`.

You have to wait the end of your `get` call and assign the value of the resulting JSON car object in the success callback of your `http` service.

Comment: shouldn't there be an error here as well? like 'undefined has no property named brakes' or some such?

Comment: Yep, he maybe hasn't checked his console.

Comment: @Aperçu thanks, you put me on the right track. The get method accepts a callback to be executed upon completion of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Even if that *would* work, I think there's a better way.

```
<div>{{car.engine}} - {{car[selectedPartKey]}}</div>
```

That way, you can just change the value of `selectedPartKey` to `'brakes'`. Your way, if `car`'s values change, it won't be reflected...

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer from Apercu is correct. You can also use more general solution which is using $watch. In that case you write this:

```
$scope.$watch('car',function(newValue) {
  $scope.selectedCarPart = newValue['brakes'];
}, true);
```

More information about $watch can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope